# Issue in import from stripe to infusionsoft

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am working on one of my client's project. In this I have created a PHP script that fetch all Orders/Payments from stripe and import into InfusionSoft. There are multiple stripe accounts and same process will be done from same script. I am getting below error in it :

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Stripe\Error\ApiConnection' with
>   message 'Could not connect to Stripe
>   (https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges?limit=100&created%5Blte%5D=1491289880).
>   Please check your internet connection and try again. If this problem
>   persists, you should check Stripe' in
>   \stripe-php-4.2.0\lib\HttpClient\CurlClient.php on line 234

I am not getting about what this error is. Please guide me to resolve issue. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is your Internet working as it says check your Internet. What are you trying. You need to show something?

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI Yes my internet is working. And run script for 10 times but every time same error shows.

Comment: How are you tying to request show code?

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI Just running a normal PHP script. My code is very lengthy I can not paste it here. If possible please provide me your Skype id.